# Grails can't resolve plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When I try to run a grails app, I'm told that grails can't resolve the following dependencies:

```
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.grails.plugins#code-coverage;1.1.8: not found

            :: org.grails.plugins#testing;0.5: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Failed to resolve plugins.
```

So I tried `grails install-plugin code-coverage` and `grails install-plugin testing`, and received:

```
Plugin not found for name [code-coverage] and version [not specified]
```

(Specifying the version shouldn't be necessary and didn't help.)

What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced a similar problem. Have a look at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6427 it helped me.

I followed what Feroz Panwaskar said :

*"As a workaround I found you can simply reinstall the plugins that cannot be resolved. Remove from plugin reference from application.properties and run install-plugin command."*

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem after installing cloud-foundry plugin.
Simply removing plugin from application.properties file removed the error.